# Polymaps marker/point popup

Tags: html, polymaps, style, markers

I think my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525176/how-can-you-add-html-layers-to-polymaps but it seems better posted in GIS StackExchange.

I'm using the Polymaps JS library and have markers on a map. I've been able to add the title tool-tip to the markers by looking at examples.
Instead of a title/tool-tip, I would like a 'pop up' on the map. Probably better if it's when you click the marker image rather than rollover. I would like to be able to style the box that pops up.